# Trying to pass and return data from remote js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking at a lot of examples on this site and others trying to find out how to return data from a remote js file when past variables from within web page.

I just cannot work out how to do it, so any help would be appreciated

test.js file

```
function displayDay(date) {
    var day1;
    if (date == 0) {
        day1 = "test works";
        return day1;
    } else {
        day1 = "not works";
        return day1;
    }
    //switch (date) {
    //    case 0:
    //        return "Sunday";
    //    case 1:
    //        return "Monday";
    //    case 2:
    //        return "Tuesday";
    //    case 3:
    //        return "Wednesday";
    //    case 4:
    //        return "Thursday";
    //    case 5:
    //        return "Friday";
    //    case 6:
    //        return "Saturday";
    //}
}
```

Code in html

```
<script>
        //var params;
        //$.getScript(function () {
        //    params = displayDay(1);
        //    alert(params);
        //});

        test = 1;
        $.fn.displayDay = function(test) {

            alert(test);
        };
    </script>
    <script src="/Scripts/CustomScripts/test.js"></script>
```

I have tried many different options, and now I'm just confused
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your external file you create a function which you never call. In your HTML script you create a function as a plugin to jQuery which you also never call. You don't show where you load jQuery (if you do). It's really not clear what these snippets are supposed to be doing.

You could try this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/CustomScripts/test.js"></script>
<script>

    var test = 1;
    var retVal = displayDay(test);
    alert(retVal);

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I have just got myself really confused with this, have spent from 2 this afternoon looking through websites trying to find examples but I must be entering the wrong search phrase as I have not found many doing what I want

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks, been on this for hours and it was that easy :-(